# How to show/hide subreport in ssrs?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS. 
What I am trying to do is create a drop down list for every tables name and show table that is selected from the drop down list and hide rest of the tables.

Comment: please explain or saw hows your main report and subreport designed?

Comment: I have created a table based contains ID and name of the subreport. This table is used for drop down list. In the main report I have inserted multiple sub reports each subreport contains table. So I need to show only subreport that is choosen from drop down list. Please let me know if you need more information.